# Error when using set on a list of tuples

Tags: python, set

I have a matrix of data.I don't understand why do i get the unhashable type error when performing set on the list of tuples:

```
pairs=list(set(map(lambda line:{line[Column.TO],line[Column.FROM]},self.DataMatrix)))
```

line[Column.TO] is a string and DataMatrix is a list of lists

Comment: You're not using `set()` on a list of tuples... check the result of your `map()` statement.

Comment: `set` is unhashable. Change it to `tuple`: Change `{line[Column.TO],line[Column.FROM]}` to `(line[Column.TO], line[Column.FROM])` and (eventually) do some additional filtering later.

Comment: I need the unique pairs generated from the map function

Comment: @CristiFati OP could use [**`frozenset`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instead

Comment: Good one @PeterWood !

Comment: But i dont get the error : unhashable.I am not performing any hashing on the set's elements i just create a list from them,

Comment: You're not, but *Python* automatically does that, in this case when creating the set (`list(` **`set`** `(map`) from the generator/list returned by `map` which contains elements of type `set` (returned by `lambda`).

Comment: I didn't know { } means creating a set.I thought you can use it when creating anonymous objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `set()` on a list of tuples, you are using `set()` on a list of `set()`s. Change your brackets `{}` to parentheses `()`:

```
pairs=list(set(map(lambda line:(line[Column.TO],line[Column.FROM]),self.DataMatrix)))
```

For example, the following demonstrates how to find "the unique pairs generated from the map function".

```
In [23]: self.DataMatrix = [[1,2,5],[3,4,5],[1,2,6]]

In [24]: Column.TO
Out[24]: 0

In [25]: Column.FROM
Out[25]: 1

In [26]: pairs=list(set(map(lambda line:(line[Column.TO],line[Column.FROM]),self.DataMatrix)))

In [27]: pairs
Out[27]: [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: I wanted to create anonymous objects that's why i thought { } can be used.

Comment: I see. `{1,2}` creates a `set`. `{1:2}` creates a `dict`. `(1,2)` (or `1,2` in some cases) creates a tuple. `[1,2]` creates a `list`. Confusingly, `{}` creates a `dict`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Being unhashable, `sets` cannot be members of a `set`. And while you are at it turning those sets into `tuples` or `frozensets`, pls get rid of that `map` with `lambda` in favor of a generator expression:

```
pairs = list(set((line[Column.TO],line[Column.FROM]) for line in self.DataMatrix))
```

Comment: So basically when i am applying the map construct it generates a set?

Comment: @user1913744 No, when you apply the brackets `{}` it generates a set. I.e. your `lambda` expression returns a set, so your `map()` function returns a list of sets.

Comment: Oh....i understand now.It wasn't my intention to create a set in the map function.I just wanted to apply the map with a custom predicate for the data and get the unique's after.

Comment: A minor correction to my previous statement: `map()` doesn't return a `list` in Python3. It returns an iterator that can generate such a list. But that doesn't change the point I was making.